# Gem Install PG mysterious error extconf.rb related

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rubygems, pg

I am trying to update my pg gem and I am getting the following error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
/Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:853:in `block in find_header'
    from /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
    from /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/larson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:852:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:40:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/larson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/larson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.13.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

I tried searching for the mkmf.log file and couldn't find it. I tried a couple of approaches, including putting the directory of the pg_conf file but nothing has worked so far. I am trying this on 10.6.8. snow leopard and my ruby is 1.9.2-p290. I have pg 9.1 installed.

I tried this:

gem install pg

gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config

This issue appeared after I replaced my macbook pro hard drive and restored the system via time machine. Should I reinstall XCode? Any other suggestions?

Comment: There are usually relevant details to be had in the mkmf.log as the output suggests. If you look in there, and post any errors you find, it will make troubleshooting your particular situation easier.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that reinstalling from time machine destroys links to the dev tools. Reinstalling XCode and updating rvm did the trick for me.

Comment: Oh, good to know! Glad you got things working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I got round it by updating rvm:

```
rvm get latest
rvm reload
rvm --force install 1.9.2
```

Comment: I received the same error for a different gem (Atomic) and using this technic saved me too. Thank you!

Comment: This didn't work for me - all those steps were successful but the error remains.